# Supervisor hierachy level logic by just using while loop

Tags: logic

I have tp create a fast formula in fusion application. fast formula is simple english mathematical calculation which uses while and if and not many functions from other languages - C, JAVA etc.

I have to create a fast formula which caluclated the manager hiearchy.

eg :

If tony is ceo of the company and karthik and mutthu are suboordinates.
and karthik further has SMITH as a sub ordinate then tony is at level 0,
Karthik and muthu at 1 and smith at 2. It like traversing down the tree.

Can anyone please suggest a logic of how j can use the variable i used in the while loop to tell me the 
hierchy level. I have two functions i can use in fast formula- greatest and least.

My formula goes like :

```
/*=========== INPUT VALUES DEFAULTS BEGIN =====================*/
INPUTS ARE CMP_IV_ASSIGNMENT_ID (number), CMP_IV_PLAN_ID (number), CMP_IV_PERIOD_ID (number)
/*=========== INPUT VALUES DEFAULTS ENDS======================*/

/*================ FORMULA SECTION BEGIN =======================*/


L_PERSON_ID = 0
L_ASSIGNMENT_ID = 0



Supervisor_id = 0
L_PERSON_NUMBER = 'XXX'
L_ASSIGNMENT_ARR_ID[21] = 0
L_JOB_LEVEL = 'B - 1'
J = 1


Supervisor_id = PER_ASG_MGR_MANAGER_ASG_ID --> assignment manager id 
L_PERSON_ID = Employee id 

WHILE (J < 10) LOOP
(



L_PERSON_ID = Employee id 
L_ASSIGNMENT_ID = Supervisor_id


L_ASSIGNMENT_ARR_ID[J] = PER_ASG_MGR_MANAGER_ASG_ID
Supervisor_id = L_ASSIGNMENT_ARR_ID[J]
J = J + 1

)


RETURN L_PERSON_ID , L_ASSIGNMENT_ID

/*================ FORMULA SECTION END =======================*/
```

I know many ppl wont know the formula rules. But i just need the logic of how i can use while loop and return j to reflect the hierchy level.CEO being 0 , his subordinate being 1 so on and so forth.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Oracle has pretty advanced and flexible tools for what you need; the pseudo-column LEVEL encodes exactly the information you are looking for. If you are trying to do it "on your own" for whatever reasons, this is not an ORACLE question - you should remove the tag. Meanwhile I will flag this question for suggested removal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP wants to reinvent the wheel (to implement from scratch the LEVEL pseudocolumn from hierarchical queries). This makes it not an Oracle question.

Comment: @mathguy- Fusion uses fast formulas which is a simple english language. In Fusion you cannot create plsql codes because u do not have access to backend.

Comment: And what does that have to do with Oracle?